# Jquery animation from a corner inward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I have a grid of four divs.  When the user clicks one, it clones it, and places it over the original one.  Then it animates about 2x's bigger.  The thing is, I would like it to animate from the outside corner depending on where it is.  IE. when it is top left, it would animate from the top left corner, bottom right, bottom right corner.  Has anyone ever done this before?  Thanks

```
$clonedElement.animate({
          height:650, width:700, position:'absolute'
        }, 500, function(){ $('.cloned_object > ul').toggle(); });
```

This is my animation function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you all:

```
var leftPos = $('#invitedToChatCell').position().left;
var topPos = $('#invitedToChatCell').position().top;
$clonedElement.animate({
     height:650, width:700, position:'absolute', left:leftPos, top:topPos 
}, 500, function(){ $('.cloned_object > ul').toggle(); });
```

Just had to animate the top and left positions too.  Hope that helps someone!